# Unable to use uploaded .csv data under Jmeter getting error message

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, ruby-jmeter

I am learning Jmeter use id=2172797 appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22
and now Unable to read data from uploaded .csv file getting error message like ; Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException under Jmeter.

Added screen for your reference.[image]

[image]

**Please help me.
Thanks**

Comment: you failed to read from CSV, show the CSV Data Set Config and check the file location is correct

Comment: thanks for your reply i am using right path as well as right data set but again same issues hapapens.

Comment: Please show image of your CSV data set config

Comment: can you plz share your email address in comments so i will send it details to you.

Comment: no, you need to attached it to question, you can do it be text or click on CSV data set config and click Ctrl+G to capture image

Answer (score 1):

Double check your `${id}` and `${appid}` variable values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, the error you're getting most probably indicates that both variables are not resolved into their values and `$` is an illegal character in the [HTTP Request URL Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)

Check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about troubleshooting JMeter tests